# dev tag not showing even i set background color but it is not showing

Tags: html, css

dev tag not showing even i set background color but it is not showing and the other issue is i set the width and height property in css style but when i open inspect element  my dev tag does not receive these width and height command ands these are the errors showing to me in browser console

```
positioning.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
positioning.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
positioning.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
positioning.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
positioning.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
positioning.html:45 Live reload enabled.
favicon.ico:1 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
positioning.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
positioning.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Comment: can you check if you are setting the right MIME type when calling the style.css in your index.html?

Comment: does the stylesheet start with comments? if yes try removing them and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

the css isn't being applied into your html file perhaps you forgot to link the css with the html file or perhaps you have a typo somewhere in the link tag it should look something like this   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`